# Get to get TreeView node using a DataItem ID in UI for ASPNET MVC

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

How can I get a TreeView node using a DataItem ID in UI for ASPNET MVC?  Obviously the code won't work but I'm looking for something like this:

```
var treeview = $("#OrganizationTree").data("kendoTreeView");

var node = treeview.GetNodeByDataItemID(1234);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your DS has a schema model which defines the id field (or you're using the default),

```
var dataItem = treeview.dataSource.get(id)
```

should work.

If you have a dataItem and want to get the DOM node, you're probably looking for [findByUid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#methods-findByUid):

```
treeview.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  How does it know what the name of my data ID property is to compare the value?  I basically want to do the opposite of this: `var dataID = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode).ID`.  I want to pass in the data ID (not the node ID) and get back the node (or the uid for the node).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your terminology; if you have the model's id, you can get the model from the data source, then you get the uid from the model, then you can search with findByUid

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do (find the node by my data model's ID property) but your code isn't working for me.  I'll run some isolated tests and see if I can get it to work that way first.

Comment: unless your id field is "id", you'll need to define the DS schema to tell the DS which field to use; or you simply get ds.data() and .filter on it with function(item) { return item.ID === 1234 }

Comment: Your code worked isolated.  I think the issue is that my treeview isn't finished binding when the `treeview.dataSource.get(id)` is being called (even though I'm calling it after get() is called).  I probably need to tie it into the onDataBound method or something.

Comment: if you're calling DS.read() separately, you can use the returned promise to do things once the request is completed (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-read); using the dataBound event should also work

Comment: Good to know!  However, won't the .read() return when only the first level is databound?  Or will it return after all the node levels are bound?  The node I add is always going to be one or more levels down the tree.

Comment: per request / level; I see now that your question lacked a lot of relevant information - you should add those details (loadOnDemand, what you're actually trying to do and so on); I'm still not sure what you're actually doing, so it's hard to answer your question